# Running a looping function and killing it when required Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, model-view-controller

I am using tkinter to build my application for testing something. I have a start button which starts a function `myFunc()` which is defined something like this:

```
def myFunc():
    for i in range(20):
        # do something which takes 0.5sec to execute
```

And I have another button which should stop this function when pressed, even if its not fully executed.
There are 2 problems here. First, the loop in `myFunc()` takes 0.5*20=10seconds to execute, which will freeze my application for that long. I can use threading to overcome this but the second problem is if I use `someThread.join()` as the command for the stop button, it will still wait until the function is executed. Also, although the GUI is not frozen while `myFunc()` is running, it hangs when I press stop button (because now its waiting until the function completes). So I need to kill the thread and stop executing that function AS SOON AS the stop button is pressed. This is a necessity.
I read everywhere on the internet that its not recommended to kill a thread. How do I do this elegantly? I dont want any problems or freezing. I just want the function to stop executing `myFunc()` the instant I press the stop button.

Full source code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from threading import Thread

def myFunc():
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.5)
    print('DONE')

def start():
    someThread.start()

def stop():
    someThread.join()
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My app')
someThread = Thread(target=myFunc)
ttk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start).pack()
ttk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What would be the results if you kill the thread, and have you tried it out?

Comment: You can't kill threads.

Comment: So how do I achieve this?

Comment: @KeyShoe Managed to do it will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

We would need to define a variable such as `stopped` which will tell the code if to stop the for loop or not. I have also added `print('hi')` and `print('hi')` to check if `def stop()` is triggered or not and if the for loop stopped or not.

**Code**

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from threading import Thread

def myFunc():
    global stopped
    for i in range(20):
        print('hi')
        if stopped == True: #checks if stopped is True or False
            break
        time.sleep(.5)
    print('DONE')

def start():
    someThread.start()

def stop():
    global stopped
    stopped = True #makes stopped True which will stop the for loop/thread
    print('triggered')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('My app')
someThread = Thread(target=myFunc)
ttk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start).pack()
ttk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop).pack()
stopped = False #stopped is false so the for loop can run
root.mainloop()
```

`hi and triggered`

```
hi
hi
hi
triggered #pressed stop
hi
DONE
```